# WordPress with Advanced Custom Fields (max_input_vars and security)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

Because a client's needs, we are using a WordPress over GAE. They are using a plugin named Advanced Custom Fields Repeater and they are having issues to publish a content that uses that plugin. This content has several custom fields (I think the problem is that they are abusing of ACF quantity on a single content). I readed about increasing `max_input_vars` parameter in `php.ini` and/or Suhosin. I am conscious about the fact that GAE has their own PHP runtime and isn't easy to tweak these variables.

On the other hand my question is about security: We can talk with Google to find a solution but according to this article  increasing this number has a security risk:
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/171-PHP-Vulnerability-May-Halt-Millions-of-Servers.html

My questions are: Is true that? Can we recommend client to choose another plugin for the same task but without need to use a huge number of POST variables? Are there performance lacks using this plugin (according the article, to have more variables in a single request translates in an increment of time to put these variables into an array to pass to PHP)?

Comment: Are you getting an error related to `max_input_vars` or is this a hunch?

Comment: I'm not getting any error at all. Publishing this particular content fails after several minutes "loading". The rest of the site is working normally. I think the issue is related with `max_input_vars` because looking for this problem, I have found that is the most common error. For example:

http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/max_input_vars-solution-not-working-for-me/

http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/03/02/wordpress-custom-fields-not-saving-phps-max_input_vars-may-be-to-blame/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089270/max-input-vars-and-acf

Comment: Is there anything listed in the app engine logs? Set your error reporting level to something high enough to display them on and make sure error logging is enabled.